# MySQL 5.1 encoding problem Entity framework core

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, entity-framework-core

I need to read data from old MySQL 5.1. I don't have write access to this database. There is problem with characters like `č`, `ň`.

The only way I was able to read this characters correctly (on windows machine) was `SET NAMES UTF8;`, open rows in client (HeidiSQL) and then export to CSV using `Unicode Big Endian` encoding. Not even HeidiSQL client or MySQL from command line work.

How can I read this in entity framework core? I tried to use various charsets in connection string without success. I think  there should be some kind of manual conversion.

Example: When I use UTF8 character set:

`č` - is returned as `è` - (c3a8)

`ň` - is returned as `ò` - (c3b2)

latin1 does not work at all

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';

character_sets_dir          /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database      latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        latin1
character_set_system        utf8

SHOW CHARACTER SET;

Charset     Description Default collation   Maxlen
big5        Big5                Traditional             Chinese big5_chinese_ci 2
12.08       DEC                 West European           dec8_swedish_ci         1
cp850       DOS                 West European           cp850_general_ci        1
hp8         HP                  West European           hp8_english_ci          1
koi8r       KOI8-R              Relcom Russian          koi8r_general_ci        1
latin1      cp1252              West European           latin1_swedish_ci       1
latin2      ISO 8859-2          Central European        latin2_general_ci       1
swe7        7bit                Swedish                 swe7_swedish_ci         1   
ascii       US                  ASCII                   ascii_general_ci        1
ujis        EUC-JP              Japanese                ujis_japanese_ci        3
sjis        Shift-JIS           Japanese                sjis_japanese_ci        2
hebrew      ISO 8859-8          Hebrew                  hebrew_general_ci       1
tis620      TIS620              Thai                    tis620_thai_ci          1   
euckr       EUC-KR              Korean                  euckr_korean_ci         2   
koi8u       KOI8-U              Ukrainian               koi8u_general_ci        1
gb2312      GB2312              Simplified Chinese      gb2312_chinese_ci       2
greek       ISO 8859-7          Greek                   greek_general_ci        1
cp1250      Windows             Central European        cp1250_general_ci       1
gbk         GBK                 Simplified Chinese      gbk_chinese_ci          2   
latin5      ISO 8859-9          Turkish                 latin5_turkish_ci       1
armscii8    ARMSCII-8           Armenian                armscii8_general_ci     1
utf8        UTF-8               Unicode                 utf8_general_ci         3   
ucs2        UCS-2               Unicode                 ucs2_general_ci         2   
cp866       DOS                 Russian                 cp866_general_ci        1
keybcs2     DOS                 Kamenicky Czech-Slovak  keybcs2_general_ci      1
macce       Mac                 Central European        macce_general_ci        1
macroman    Mac                 West European           macroman_general_ci     1
cp852       DOS                 Central European        cp852_general_ci        1
latin7      ISO                 8859-13 Baltic          latin7_general_ci       1
cp1251      Windows             Cyrillic                cp1251_general_ci       1
cp1256      Windows             Arabic                  cp1256_general_ci       1
cp1257      Windows             Baltic                  cp1257_general_ci       1
binary      Binary              pseudo charset          binary                  1   
geostd8     GEOSTD8             Georgian                geostd8_general_ci      1
cp932       SJIS for Windows    Japanese                cp932_japanese_ci       2
eucjpms     UJIS for Windows    Japanese                eucjpms_japanese_ci     3
```

Comment: first find which charaters set is used in the table and then connect with the same character set.try latin1 also for the connection

Comment: Character set is latin1, but it does not show correct results.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Something more definite than your *…it does not show correct results*.

Comment: look if your ef core connectstimg has also latin1 as character set, also chakc the collations